# My laptop's keyboard stopped working - how do I fix it?

Tags: keyboard

I suspended my Aspire E 15 laptop (Ubuntu 18.04) for a couple of hours and when I switched it on its own keyboard wasn't working.

Then, when I plugg in a USB keyboard (which I'm now using to type this question), it does work.

The touchpad seems to work, as well as the keyboard's power on button.

I tried to rebbot it, update drivers and so on, and nothing worked.

What can I do?

Comment: Still the same problem after rebooting?

Comment: Sadly, yes. I rebooted multiple times, done sudo apt-get update / upgrade, even reinstalled its drivers manually. It was working fine till this afternoon, I did not modified the system in any way other than the usual sudo apt-get clean / autoclean I do daily

Comment: I hope not but it can be hardware failure. Test if it works by trying to access BIOS/UEFI settings. As this happens before the OS has a chance to load it will rule out one or the other, hardware or the OS.

Comment: No, it doesn't open the BIOS. Ho can I check this is an hardware failure?

Comment: It is an hardware failure. That was the test. Please contact the tech support.

Comment: Today I started the computer and the keyboard was fine. Any idea why this happened?